# Find duplicates in mulitple columns and drop rows - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, rows

If the name appears in any subsequent row, I want to drop that row. Mainly i'm not sure how to get the index of that found duplicate and then use that index number to drop it from df.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'interviewer': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Jermaine', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
        'candidate': ['Bob', 'Jermaine', 'Ahmed', 'Karl', 'Molly'],
        'year': [2012, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014], 
        'reports': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#names = pd.unique(df[['interviewer', 'candidate']].values.ravel()).tolist()

mt = []

for i, c in zip(df.interviewer, df.candidate):
    print i, c
    if i not in mt:
        if c not in mt:
            mt.append(df.loc[(df.interviewer == i) & (df.candidate == c)] )
    else:
        continue
```

My thinking was use `mt` as a list to pass to `df.drop` and drop the rows with those indices. The result I want is without seeing Molly or Jermaine appear again in indices 2 or 4 - `df.drop([2,4], inplace=True)`.

**EDITED**

I've figured out a way to create the list of indices I want to pass to drop:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'interviewer': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Jermaine', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
        'candidate': ['Bob', 'Jermaine', 'Ahmed', 'Karl', 'Molly'],
        'year': [2012, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014], 
        'reports': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#print df
counter = -1
bad_rows = []
names = []
for i, c in zip(df.interviewer, df.candidate):
    print i, c

    counter += 1
    print counter
    if i not in names:
        names.append(i)
    else:
        bad_rows.append(counter)
    if c not in names:
        names.append(c)
    else:
        bad_rows.append(counter)

#print df.drop(bad_rows)
```

However there has to be a smarter way to do this, maybe something along  @Ami_Tavory answer for itertools?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: I tried `df.drop_duplicates(['candidate', 'interviewer'])` but that only works when both match. I'm looking for `when seen name found - drop the row` functionality

Answer (score 1):

(At the time when this answer was written, there was some discrepancy between the verbal description and the code example.)

You can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) to check if an item appears in a different column, like so:

```
In [5]: df.candidate.isin(df.interviewer)
Out[5]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
Name: candidate, dtype: bool
```

Consequently, you can do something like

```
df[~df.candidate.isin(df.interviewer)]
```

Note that this matches your original code, not your specification of *subsequent* rows. If you want to drop only if the rows are subsequent, I'd go with `itertools`, something like:

```
In [18]: bads = [i for ((i, cn), (j, iv)) in itertools.product(enumerate(df.candidate), enumerate(df.interviewer)) if j >=i and cn == iv]

In [19]: df[~df.index.isin(bads)]
Out[19]: 
  candidate interviewer  reports  year
0       Bob       Jason        4  2012
2     Ahmed    Jermaine       31  2013
3      Karl        Jake        2  2014
4     Molly         Amy        3  2014
```

Also, if you want to drop the subsequent rows, simply change things to

```
In [18]: bads = [j for ((i, cn), (j, iv)) in itertools.product(enumerate(df.candidate), enumerate(df.interviewer)) if j >=i and cn == iv]
```

Comment: Thanks but wasn't quite what I wanted - poor code in original question. I put up the answer now so please advise it there is a shortcut through itertools

Comment: that drops first instance of 'Molly' in index=1 whereas it should be dropping index=4 - 2nd instance of 'Molly'; a subsequent occurrence. I'm using same idea as `pd.drop_duplicates([subset], keep='first')`.

Comment: @noblerthanoedipus So in your question, " If the name appears in any subsequent row, I want to drop that row" means "I want to drop the subsequent row"?

Comment: I meant the next row which contains `name` in either column should be dropped

Answer (score 0):

I made a function for what I want to do. Using `df.index` makes it safe to use for any numerical index.

```
def drop_dup_rows(df):
    names = []
    for i, c, ind in zip(df.interviewer, df.candidate, df.index.tolist()):
        if any(x in names for x in [i, c]):
            df.drop(ind, inplace=True)
        else:
            names.extend([i,c])
    return df
```